# Difference between regular dogs and Conan?

Tags: dogs

This may be a dumb question... I know.

Today I was reading this [The NY Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/28/us/politics/trump-baghdadi-dog-conan.html) about a military dog participating in last week's ISIS raid that killed al-Baghdadi.

So I'm thinking... this must be a bad-ass military dog. He's such an awesome dog that I only knew he was "Conan" because his name was declassified by the Pentagon.

Generally speaking, what are the differences between my dog and "Conan"? Does "Conan" pee and poop like the rest of them or is he more disciplined?

Do dogs like "Conan" suffer from PTSD where they wake up in the middle of the night and attack their owner? Do they play with regular toys like regular dogs?

For example, my dog enjoys bacon, plays with a sophisticated electronic toy, and only drinks filtered water. Would "Conan" scoff at these luxuries knowing that he only played with sand in Syria or would he be ecstatic *because he can play with these great toys* and he's not in Syria anymore?

Another example: my dog gets sad whenever I cut myself while cooking. Would "Conan" feel sadness also? Or will he just ignore me because he knows it's not a bullet wound or a commando raid?

I've seen military dogs at airports, and they look very serious. He didn't even make eye contact with me when I started making silly sounds.

Answer (score 1):

'Conan' is whats known as a military dog or personal protection dog assigned to a dog handler in the army.

These dogs go through extensive and precise training in order to subdue, disable or in some cases kill a target.

They need the right character, confidence, drive, toughness and ability to carry out these tasks and go through the training. So only certain working breeds are considered, and even then its down to the character of the dog itself.

These dogs are not typically kept as pets and will likely live in a kennel at a base or outside the home of a serving handler, and in rare cases in the handlers home. These dogs will be high in drive making their defence and offence nature strong which can lead to aggressive or destructive behaviour in some cases if not kept suitably occupied.

But these dogs are incredibly well trained. Trained to only respond to their owner or handler. Chances are you wont even know what the commands are. They tend to avoid the conventional 'Sit' etc. So this is why it didnt respond to you making noises. Because it is essentially waiting for its owners interaction.

They will likely have toys mainly used for training purposes or for stimulation when not being utilised.

Dogs as far as im aware can suffer PTSD like trauma but as always it can manifest in various ways, but these dogs are highly scrutinised when selected for this training so chances of dogs like 'Conan' suffering from this are slim to none.